# While animating opacity, z-index not respected

Tags: css, animation, z-index

I'm on my first SVG "montage" animation and I have this little problem.
3 elements positioned "absolute" with corresponding z-index. The 2 first SVG "object > embed" and the third a simple div with bg color or gradient. When the 3rd element animates it's opacity from 0 to 1 it gets in front of the other elements, and when the animation is done it goes to it's rightful z-index position. Is there a way to prevent this !!?? I'm adding a picture demonstrating the unwanted effect while animating. Many thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm13T.jpg)
HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper_u">
    <object>
        <embed src="ubeo-u.svg">
    </object>
</div>
<div id="wrapper_shape">
    <object>
        <embed src="ubeo-shape.svg">
    </object>
</div>
<div id="wrapper_shadow">
</div>
```